# Email and email sequence script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that i'm going to use to send email to a list of clients that I haven't been able to get hold of over the phone.

Here is how it is supposed to work:

The script is time triggered and is sending a email sequence as you can see down below.

First email sent ---> if no response ----> send second email -----> if no response -----> send third email -----> if no response then stop

If they reply to the first or the second one then stop sending email.

Everything works except the last part and that is when someone replies. When someone replies it is supposed to put a timestamp in Col C so the answer gets recorded and then stop the script.

I'm not a expert that it this type of script so all help and tips is highly appreciated.

Here is a link the the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gRjF4QjLunF5jRE1qGj2hTSlIwyvPsI3h78bacJBDHI/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  // Replace the sheet ID and email column with your own
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gRjF4QjLunF5jRE1qGj2hTSlIwyvPsI3h78bacJBDHI/edit#gid=0').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var emails = sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat();
  var sentDates = sheet.getRange('B2:B').getValues().flat();
  var responseDates = sheet.getRange('C2:C').getValues().flat();
 
  // Replace the email subjects and bodies with your own
  var subject1 = 'First Email Subject';
  var body1 = 'First Email Body';
  var subject2 = 'Second Email Subject';
  var body2 = 'Second Email Body';
  var subject3 = 'Third Email Subject';
  var body3 = 'Third Email Body';
 
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    if (emails[i]) { // Make sure the cell is not empty
      if (responseDates[i]) {
        continue; // Skip if response already recorded
      }
      if (!sentDates[i]) {
        // Send first email
        MailApp.sendEmail(emails[i], subject1, body1);
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue(new Date()); // Record sent date/time in column B
        Utilities.sleep(1000); // Wait for 1 second to avoid Gmail's sending limits
      } else if (!responseDates[i] && new Date() - sentDates[i] > 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
        // Send third email if no response after 3 days
        MailApp.sendEmail(emails[i], subject3, body3);
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 3).setValue(new Date()); // Record response date/time in column C
        Utilities.sleep(1000); // Wait for 1 second to avoid Gmail's sending limits
      } else if (!responseDates[i] && new Date() - sentDates[i] > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
        // Send second email if no response after 1 day
        MailApp.sendEmail(emails[i], subject2, body2);
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue(new Date()); // Record sent date/time in column B
        Utilities.sleep(1000); // Wait for 1 second to avoid Gmail's sending limits
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are reading response dates before you setValue into column C so changing the value in column C will not affect the values in responseDates() unless you rerun that getValues();

Comment: Would you please clarify something... `When someone replies it is supposed to put a timestamp in Col C so the answer gets recorded and then stop the script.` When someone replies, do you expect that a/the script will enter a timestamp in Column C or will this be done manually?

Comment: @Tedinoz Great question and I expect that the script will enter a timestamp in Col C so it gets automated

Comment: I suggest that you've developed a script based on an untested idea that _assumes_ that you will be able to identify specific responses to specific email(s). Would you agree that this is the **real** question - `how to populate response dates`? Would you summarise your research on this and any attempts that you have made to resolve the issue yourself.

Comment: @Tedinoz That is the real question "How to populate response dates". I have looked at other forums and got the answers that it is possible to automate that through script but I'm not an expert and I learn as I go when tackling these problems. I'm going to look into how to add a IF statement to add the timestamps to Col C, another solution would could be to export emails from Gmail to Sheets and do a matching function through a array and do a IF statement to stop the automation on those who gets matched. Again I'm not a expert and I'm posting here to get some help so any help is appreciated

Comment: @EricMorandeau Ok. ‘If’ and ‘values in Column C’ are the least of your problems. **THE** issue is to be able to query Gmail to identify whether there has been a response to one or more specific emails sent by you (??) to a specific addressee within a specific time period. I _do_ understand that you are developing your skills, so I would suggest that you first work manually in Gmail to try an develop a query that will test for a response to a given addressee/subject/dare combination. Once you have that, you can use those parameters to create a script to make the query and evaluate the result.